# Unable to delete all files from temporary folders in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am using the following code to delete all files from a particular folder:

```
Sub DeleteFiles(Folder As String)
    If Directory.Exists(Folder) Then
        For Each _file As String In Directory.GetFiles(Folder)

            File.Delete(_file)

        Next
        For Each _folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Folder)

            DeleteFiles(_folder)
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Whenever I use the above code to delete all files from "C:\Temp" by calling it using  DeleteFiles("C:\Temp"), It deletes all the files successfully, but whenever I try to use the same code for deleting  files in "C:\Windows\TEMP\", it breaks the operation saying that the file is in use. I want that the code should not raise an exception and stop deleting the files right-away. If the file cannot be deleted, the code should move on to the next file and try deleting it. This way, it should be able to delete maximum possible files from that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle exceptions raised by `File.Delete()` using a `Try....Catch...` statement. I'm not a VB coder (I'm surprised to find myself answering this question), but something like this should work:

```
Sub DeleteFiles(Folder As String)
    If Directory.Exists(Folder) Then
        For Each _file As String In Directory.GetFiles(Folder)
            Try 
                File.Delete(_file)
            Catch e As System.IO.IOException
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
            End Try
        Next
        For Each _folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Folder)

            DeleteFiles(_folder)
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

This will catch an `System.IO.IOException` exception, log that it was received, and then ignore it. Note that this will catch a number of other `File.Delete()` related exceptions such as `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`, `System.IO.PathTooLongException`, etc. If you want to catch these, you must add a `Catch` clause for each before the more general `System.IO.IOException`. The possible exceptions are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), along with an example of using `File.Delete()` - you just need to read the docs.

You might like to also look at [Directory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to recursively delete a directory, its files, and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop an exception being thrown.  What you need to do is catch the exception, process it as appropriate (which may mean just ignoring it) and move on.  That means putting a `Try...Catch` block inside your first loop.  That way, when `File.Delete` throws an exception, you can catch it, ignore it and the loop will continue.

Be sure to catch only the type of exception that you expect to be thrown though.  Otherwise, something completely unexpected may be causing an issue and you're just ignoring it, which is bad.  Only ignore exceptions that you reasonably expect and know can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim temp As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP")
    Dim k As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(temp)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To k.Length
        On Error Resume Next
        Kill(k(i))
        System.IO.File.Delete(k(i))
    Next
```